# Apache2 with Tomcat7 worker error

Tags: tomcat7, ubuntu-16.04, apache2.4, mod-jk

I am trying to configure mod_jk for apache2 in front of tomcat7 but I'm getting a following error:

> mod_jk.log[Error]:jk_uri_worker_map.c (580): Could not find worker
>   with name '/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/workers.properties' in uri map post
>   processing

`workers.properties` is in `tomcat7/conf/`

`jk.conf` is in `apache2/mods-enabled/`

`000-default.conf` is in `apache2/sites-enabled/`

**workers.properties**

```
`workers.tomcat_home=/var/lib/tomcat7
workers.java_home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
ps=/
worker.list=worker1
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=xxxx.com
worker.worker1.port=8009
worker.ajp13_worker.lbfactor=1
worker.worker1.mount=/*
# configure jk-status
worker.list=jk-status
worker.jk-status.type=status
worker.jk-status.read_only=true
#configure jk-manager
worker.list=jk-manager
worker.jk-manager.type=status`
```

**jk.conf**

```
`<IfModule jk_module>
JkWorkersFile /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/workers.properties
JkLogFile /var/log/apache2/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel debug
JkShmFile /var/log/apache2/jk-runtime-status
JkOptions +RejectUnsafeURI +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat
JkWatchdogInterval 60
    JkMount /* worker1
<Location /jk-status>
    # Inside Location we can omit the URL in JkMount
    JkMount jk-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
<Location /jk-manager>
    # Inside Location we can omit the URL in JkMount
    JkMount jk-manager
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>`
```

**000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory /var/www/html>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
 AllowOverride All
 Order allow,deny
 allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
JkMount /* worker1
JkMountCopy On
</VirtualHost>
```

**mod_jk.log**

```
[Tue Mar 06 12:27:55.370 2018] [14733:140153319872384] [debug]     wc_get_worker_for_name::jk_worker.c (120): did not find a worker /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/workers.properties
[Tue Mar 06 12:27:55.370 2018] [14733:140153319872384] [error] extension_fix::jk_uri_worker_map.c (580): Could not find worker with name '/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/workers.properties' in uri map post processing.
[Tue Mar 06 12:27:55.370 2018] [14733:140153319872384] [debug] wc_get_worker_for_name::jk_worker.c (120): did not find a worker /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/workers.properties
[Tue Mar 06 12:27:55.370 2018] [14733:140153319872384] [error] extension_fix::jk_uri_worker_map.c (580): Could not find worker with name '/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/workers.properties' in uri map post processing.
```

Comment: Improved readability, moved the error message to the text question, removed unnecessary blockquotes.

Comment: Got the solution Issue was not with worker, but a firewall. ajp13 is working perfectly

Comment: I suggest adding the solution as an answer, and marking it as accepted since no one answered it so far. It might help someone in the future.

Comment: My server is on AWS Ec2 Instance , as ajp13 uses port 8009 we must open the port with only our server IP for internal communication. This was no where shown in mod-jk log also.